# Creating a basic direction vector in Julia using Set Index

Tags: indexing, julia

I created a vector full of zeros and want to replace them with certain values at certain indices. I tried doing this by first creating my vector and then using the setindex function.
Here is my code:

```
n=4 
A = [ 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.0; 2.0 1.0 0.0 1.0] 
basic_col_indices = [1, 2] 
db = -1 * inv(B) * A[:, 3] 
z = zeros(n) 
setindex!(z, [db], basic_col_indices);
```

The error I am getting is Dimension Mismatch: tried to assign 1 element to 2 destinations, is there anyway I could assign all of db to those specific destinations? Here is my output for db, and this why I am getting confused because db is a 2-element vector that I am assigning to 2 destinations.

`2-element Vector{Float64}:   0.3333333333333333  -0.6666666666666666`

Comment: simply remove the square brackets: `setindex!(z, db, basic_col_indices);`

Comment: What is `B`? Please provide the complete code.

Comment: @Shayan my B was     B = A[:, basic_col_indices]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use broadcasting to assign all the elements of `db` to the elements of `z` indexed by `basic_col_indices` like this `z[basic_col_indices] .= db`. As shown in the Julia help prompt, *The syntax `a[i,j,...] = x` is converted by the
compiler to (`setindex!(a, x, i, j, ...); x`).*

Back to the error in your code, `[db]` is a single `Vector{Vector{Float64}}` which means you're trying to assign 1 element to 2 destinations. To fix this, remove the square brackets as suggested by @AhmedAEK.

```
n = 4 
A = [ 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.0; 2.0 1.0 0.0 1.0] 
basic_col_indices = [1, 2] 
B = A[:,basic_col_indices]
db = -1 * inv(B) * A[:, 3] 
z = zeros(n)
setindex!(z, db, basic_col_indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to broadcast the `setindex!` function (note we do not want to broadcast over `v` so we use `Ref(v)`):

```
v = zeros(Int,5);
setindex!.(Ref(v), [22,44], [2, 4]);
```

This yields:

```
julia> v
5-element Vector{Int64}:
  0
 22
  0
 44
  0
```